# How to use "xargs" properly when argument list is too long

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Can someone please give me an example of using xargs on the below operation?

```
tar c $dir/temp/*.parse\
    | lzma -9 > $dir/backup/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')-archive.tar.lzma
```

I get the error from bash "**/bin/tar: Argument list too long**"

Particularily I am trying to do LZMA compression on about 4,500 files; so this isn't surprising.  I just don't know how to modify the above to use xargs and get rid of the error! Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Expanding on CristopheDs answer and assuming you're using bash:

```
tar c --files-from <(find $dir/temp -maxdepth 1 -name "*.parse") | lzma -9 > $dir/backup/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')-archive.tar.lzma
```

The reason `xargs` doesn't help you here is that it will do multiple invocations until all arguments have been used. This won't help you here since that will create *several* tar archives, which you don't want.

Comment: i did the mistake with find doing multiple invokations of tar before, thinking when putting them in a { ... } | lzma... it work. but then it would print the tar header again each time :p

Comment: In case anyone finds this and isn't clear *how* it works, `<(command)` in bash creates a "named file descriptor" attached to the output of `command`. So in this case, `tar` sees an argument like `--files-from /dev/fd123`, but reading from the "file" `/dev/fd123` just gives it the output of `find`, without the need for an actual temporary file.

Answer (score 15):

As a side note:

Always, always avoid xargs(1).  It's a broken tool and is only remotely useful if you use it with the -0 option.  Even then, it's almost always better to use find(1)'s -exec option, or a simple for or while loop.

Why is xargs so bad?  Firstly, it splits input on whitespace, meaning all your filenames that **contain** whitespace will cause havoc.  Secondly, it *tries* to be a smartass, and *parse quotes* for you.  Which only leads to more headaches as you use it on filenames that **contain** quotes as part of the filename, such as songs: "*I don't wanna miss a thing.mp3*".  This will just make xargs puke and curse at you that you quoted its input badly.  No, you didn't:  it should just learn that **quotes do not belong in input data, they belong in shell scripts**, and xargs has no business trying to parse them.

Mind you, xargs(1) doesn't do the whitespace splitting or the quote parsing when you pass -0 to it.  It does the *right thing*, which is use NULL bytes to delimit filenames.  But that means you need to give it input that uses NULL byte-delimited filenames (such as "*find -foo -print0*").  Which brings us back to: it's better to just use find's -exec: "*find -foo -exec bar {} +*".

Comment: nice, awesome little history/explanation - much appreciated!

Comment: This is the reason why GNU Parallel was made: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/history.html

Comment: You probably meant avoid xargs in this particular case? As opposed to while loop, xargs provides control over parallelism. It's might be worth mentioning that `-d` disables quote and backslash interpretation as well

Comment: I'd argue that those filenames are the broken ones, not `xargs(1)`, which I find amazing :-)

Answer (score 5):

Use find to pipe the 'wanted' filenames to a temporary file,
and then use tar with the '-–files-from' command line option.

**Edit:**

or pipe them directly into each other to avoid the temporary file.

So: use find to list the wanted filenames | tar ... --files-from

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you want something like this?

```
find $dir/temp/ -name '*.parse' -print0 | tar --null -T - -c | lzma -9 > $dir/backup/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')-archive.tar.lzma
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Linux, you have GNU tar, and you can use the '`-F -`' or '`--files-from`' option to read the file names.

However, you can also use:

--use-compress-program="lzma -9"

to specify the compression program to use, and simply give the compresses file name as the target file for the 'tar' command.

This was necessary for 'bzip2' compression before the '`-j`' option was added.