# Help Editing Code to Fix "Argument list too long" Error

Tags: c++, bash, icu

I am currently doing some testing with a new addition to the ICU dictionary-based break iterator.
I have code that allows me to test the word-breaking on a text document but when the text document is too large it gives the error: bash: ./a.out: Argument list too long

I am not sure how to edit the code to break-up the argument list when it gets too long so that a file of any size can be run through the code.  The original code author is quite busy, would someone be willing to help out?

I tried removing the printing of what is being examined to see if that would help, but I still get the error on large files (printing what is being examined isn't necessary - I just need the result).

If the code could be modified to read the source text file line by line and export the results line by line to another text file (ending up with all the lines when it is done), that would be perfect.

The code is as follows:

```
/*
Written by George Rhoten to test how word segmentation works.
Code inspired by the break ICU sample.

Here is an example to run this code under Cygwin.

PATH=$PATH:icu-test/source/lib ./a.exe "`cat input.txt`" > output.txt

Encode input.txt as UTF-8.
The output text is UTF-8.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unicode/brkiter.h>
#include <unicode/ucnv.h>

#define ZW_SPACE "\xE2\x80\x8B"

void printUnicodeString(const UnicodeString &s) {
    int32_t len = s.length() * U8_MAX_LENGTH + 1;
    char *charBuf = new char[len];
    len = s.extract(0, s.length(), charBuf, len, NULL);
    charBuf[len] = 0;
    printf("%s", charBuf);
    delete charBuf;
}

/* Creating and using text boundaries */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ucnv_setDefaultName("UTF-8");
    UnicodeString stringToExamine("Aaa bbb ccc. Ddd eee fff.");
    printf("Examining: ");
    if (argc > 1) {
        // Override the default charset.
        stringToExamine = UnicodeString(argv[1]);
        if (stringToExamine.charAt(0) == 0xFEFF) {
            // Remove the BOM
            stringToExamine = UnicodeString(stringToExamine, 1);
        }
    }
    printUnicodeString(stringToExamine);
    puts("");

    //print each sentence in forward and reverse order
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    BreakIterator* boundary = BreakIterator::createWordInstance(NULL, status);
    if (U_FAILURE(status)) {
        printf("Failed to create sentence break iterator. status = %s", 
            u_errorName(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Result:    ");
    //print each word in order
    boundary->setText(stringToExamine);
    int32_t start = boundary->first();
    int32_t end = boundary->next();
    while (end != BreakIterator::DONE) {
        if (start != 0) {
            printf(ZW_SPACE);
        }
        printUnicodeString(UnicodeString(stringToExamine, start, end-start));
        start = end;
        end = boundary->next();
    }

    delete boundary;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks so much!
-Nathan

Comment: Ah, yes that is helpful. No, it's not to see how shell handles word-breaking - it's just for the resulting file - would you be able to help change the code to read the text line by line?

Comment: I removed my comment accidentally :-) To read from a file in c++, see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ post your code and I'll be glad to help you...

Comment: I was wondering where it went :)  The code that needs the modification to read line by line is in the question.  I don't personally know c++ - the original code was created by someone helping me with the ICU submission, but he is quite busy, so I thought I would look elsewhere.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looking at the code a little closer - it might be that you need the source of stdio.h brkiter.h and ucnv.h ... which means this might be more complex than I thought...I can get those sources to you, but no worries if it would take too much of your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below reads the content of a file whos name is given as the first parameter on the command-line and places it in a `str::buffer`. Then, instead of calling the function `UnicodeString` with `argv[1]`, use that buffer instead.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string buffer;

    if(argc > 1) {
        std::ifstream t;
        t.open(argv[1]);
        std::string line;
        while(t){
            std::getline(t, line);
            buffer += line + '\n';
        }
    }
    cout << buffer;
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

Input to `UnicodeString` should be `char*`. The function `GetFileIntoCharPointer` does that.
Note that only the most rudimentary error checking is implemented below!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

char * GetFileIntoCharPointer(char *pFile, long &lRet)
{
    FILE * fp = fopen(pFile,"rb");
    if (fp == NULL) return 0;

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    char *pData = new char[size + 1];
    lRet = fread(pData, sizeof(char), size, fp);

    fclose(fp);

    return pData;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long Len;
    char * Data = GetFileIntoCharPointer(argv[1], Len);
    std::cout << Data << std::endl;

    if (Data != NULL)
        delete [] Data;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fredrik - would you be able to fill in the details a little more? I'm at a loss...sorry!  Do replace the int main function from the old code with your code?  I tried that but I get errors: InsertZWSlarge.cpp:80:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’
InsertZWSlarge.cpp:88:5: error: ‘boundary’ does not name a type
InsertZWSlarge.cpp:91:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘while’
So I'm thinking I did it wrong...

Comment: Hi Again Fredrik!  Thanks for your help!  Sorry my experience is so limited, I still can't get it to work.  Your updated code replaces what you previously wrote right?  Perhaps it is a compatibility issue with ICU...but more likely my stupidity :P  Would you be able to put your code inline with the code I posted in the question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `Argument list too long` error message is coming from the bash shell and is happening before your code even gets started executing.

The only code you can fix to eliminate this problem is the bash source code (or maybe it is in the kernel) and then, you're always going to run into a limit. If you increase from 2048 files on command line to 10,000, then some day you'll need to process 10,001 files ;-)

There are numerous solutions to managing 'too big' argument lists.

The standardized solution is the xargs utility.

```
 find / -print | xargs echo
```

is a un-helpful, but working example.

See [How to use "xargs" properly when argument list is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683776/how-to-use-xargs-properly-when-argument-list-is-too-long) for more info.

Even xargs has problems, because file names can contain spaces, new-line chars, and other unfriendly stuff.

I hope this helps.